# No sound from speakers , audio output 'speaker' not available

Tags: sound

i'm running Ubuntu 18.04,
I had a problem with my sound for a while now. Sound automatically change into headphones as default but speakers are not shown in audio output.

But,after rebooting the desktop,the audio output set as "speaker" automatically.and speaker is working as normal.